# RegEx to extract filenames from data

Tags: regex

I have some data which I have gotten from my portable Media player. What I am trying to do is extract the .mp3 filenames from the data. The format of the mp3 file is AUD-20181015-WA0009.mp3

Files can also have file extension of wav and m4a.

Could somebody help me with the RegEx that will extract the filename

Sample data below

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Uª        MP3 D @        D @                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþ**A U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 9 0 . m p 3**   AH}                                                                                                          M4A D          D                                                            €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 8 8 . m 4 a   AH}                                                                                                         MP3 D `        D `                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 8 7 . m p 3   AH}                                                                                                         M4A D à        D à                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 8 2 . m 4 a   AH}                                                                                                         M4A D          D                                                            €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 8 1 . m 4 a   AH}                                                                                                         MP3 D €        D €                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 6 0 . m p 3   a a                                                                                                          MP3 D à        D à                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 5 9 . m p 3   AH}                                                                                                         MP3 D @        D @                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 5 7 . m p 3                                                                                                                   MP3 D `        D `                                                          €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 5 4 . m p 3                                                                                                             
   MP3 D          D                                                            €ÂŸxlÂŸÿþA U D - 2 0 1 8 1 1 1 7 - W A 0 1 4 9 . m p 3   ors
```

Thank you

Desmond

Comment: What language you are comfortable in?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl code that will extract all the filenames you are interested in.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'perlsongs.txt';
open(my $fh, $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $row = <$fh>;

$row =~ s/\s+//g;


my @matches = ( $row =~ /[\w .-]+(?:\s*m\s*p\s*3|\s*m\s*4\s*a|\s*w\s*a\s*v)/g );

foreach(@matches) {
    print "$_\n";
}
print "\ndone\n";
```

Here `perlsongs.txt` is the file that contains your binary like data.

Upon executing, it should print all the filenames you are looking for. This is the actual output for the script.

```
AUD-20181117-WA0190.mp3
AUD-20181117-WA0188.m4a
AUD-20181117-WA0187.mp3
AUD-20181117-WA0182.m4a
AUD-20181117-WA0181.m4a
AUD-20181117-WA0160.mp3
AUD-20181117-WA0159.mp3
AUD-20181117-WA0157.mp3
AUD-20181117-WA0154.mp3

done
```

Let me know if this works good for you.

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh for your help. My plan is to extract the RegEx from the perl code and use it at the website http://www.molbiotools.com/textextractor.html. I have entered [\\w .-]+(\\s*m\\s*p\\s*3|\\s*m\\s*4\\s*a|\\s*w\\s*a\\s*v into the TEXT to EXTRACT Box but not getting and return. I did remove all spaces from the data before I run it. Could I humbly ask if you could check if I entered the the correct Regex please Thanks You Desmond

Comment: @Desmond: That regex is for java where you have to escape `\` as `\\`. For perl the regex you need to use is this `[\w .-]+(?:\s*m\s*p\s*3|\s*m\s*4\s*a|\s*w\s*a\s*v)` Let me update my answer with codes in perl.

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh its working beautifully. Just to let you know my RegEx returned 10 file names where your example 9 files return are  AUD-20181117-WA0190.mp3
 AUD-20181117-WA0188.m4a
 AUD-20181117-WA0187.mp3
 AUD-20181117-WA0182.m4a
 AUD-20181117-WA0181.m4a
 AUD-20181117-WA0160.mp3
 AUD-20181117-WA0159.mp3
 AUD-20181117-WA0157.mp3
 AUD-20181117-WA0154.mp3
this one was missing from your list AUD-20181117-WA0149.mp3.  Oone again thank you for all your help

Comment: @Desmond: Good to hear it worked for you beautifully. Actually if you noticed my Java solution extracted 10 files and worked perfectly fine. Perl I never got to work earlier, so may be due to some corner case one filename got left as my perl program was not exactly same as Java. Nonetheless, you got a working solution so all good. If my answer worked for you, please consider upvoting my answer. Thank you.